# How to split gif into images

Tags: go

How can I split gif into images in go?
image/gif's DecodeAll return GIF, which contains an array of palette. But don't know how to convert each palette into an image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following:
Frames can contain transparent pixels or areas, a good example is [this image on wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#/media/File:SmallFullColourGIF.gif) which (I guess) has one of these full-color blocks per frame and the rest of the frame transparent.

This introduces a problem for you: Especially with animated GIFs, that do not use multiple frames to create a true-colored static image, the frames that `DecodeAll` returns are *not* what you actually see if you, for example, open the image in your browser.

You'll have to process the image in the same way your browser would, i.e. leave the old frames on a kind of canvas and overpaint with the new frame. **BUT** this is not always true. GIF frames can, AFAIK, contain a disposal method, specifying how (or if?) you should dispose of the frame.

Anyways, to get to your point, the most simple approach that will also work in most cases is something like

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "image/gif"
    "image/png"
    "io"
    "os"
)

// Decode reads and analyzes the given reader as a GIF image
func SplitAnimatedGIF(reader io.Reader) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Error while decoding: %s", r)
        }
    }()

    gif, err := gif.DecodeAll(reader)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    imgWidth, imgHeight := getGifDimensions(gif)

    overpaintImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight))
    draw.Draw(overpaintImage, overpaintImage.Bounds(), gif.Image[0], image.ZP, draw.Src)

    for i, srcImg := range gif.Image {
        draw.Draw(overpaintImage, overpaintImage.Bounds(), srcImg, image.ZP, draw.Over)

        // save current frame "stack". This will overwrite an existing file with that name
        file, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "<some path>", i, ".png"))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = png.Encode(file, overpaintImage)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        file.Close()
    }

    return nil
}

func getGifDimensions(gif *gif.GIF) (x, y int) {
    var lowestX int
    var lowestY int
    var highestX int
    var highestY int

    for _, img := range gif.Image {
        if img.Rect.Min.X < lowestX {
            lowestX = img.Rect.Min.X
        }
        if img.Rect.Min.Y < lowestY {
            lowestY = img.Rect.Min.Y
        }
        if img.Rect.Max.X > highestX {
            highestX = img.Rect.Max.X
        }
        if img.Rect.Max.Y > highestY {
            highestY = img.Rect.Max.Y
        }
    }

    return highestX - lowestX, highestY - lowestY
}
```

(untested, but should work)

Note that `gif.DecodeAll` can and will panic *frequently*, because a lot of the GIF images on the internet are somewhat broken. Your browser tries to decode them and will, for example, replace missing colors with black. `image/gif` will not do that, but panic instead. That's why we `defer` the `recover`.

Also, I used the `getGifDimensions` for a similar reason as stated above: single frames need not be what you see in your browser. In this case, the frames are just smaller than the complete image, that's why we have to iterate over all frames and get the "true" dimensions of the image.

If you really *really* want to do it right, you should probably read the GIF spec [GIF87a](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif87.txt), [GIF89a](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) and something like [this article](http://www.webreference.com/content/studio/disposal.html) which is a lot easier to understand. From that, you should decide how to dispose of the frames and what to do with transparency while overpainting.

**EDIT**: Some of the effects mentioned earlier can be observed easily if you split some GIFs online, for example [this](http://ezgif.com/split/ecd3597e36.gif) or [this](http://ezgif.com/split/5ea1f2a24c.gif) - play around with "Ignore optimizations" and "Redraw every frame with details from previous frames" to see what I mean.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's correct. I have taken the code from a project I've written some time ago, so I probably didn't know about it then, will fix, thanks!

Comment: draw.Draw will blend the current frame with the previous frame, right?
Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @BhoomtawathPlinsut `draw.Draw` will blend the current frame with _all_ the previous frames, which in turn were blended with their previous frames, so yes :)

Comment: One small note: the `os.Open` call inside the 'for' loop will return an error if the file doesn't exist, and it probably will not exist. A better one might be `os.OpenFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "<some path>", i, ".png"), os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0655)`

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23, thanks, I should've know that! I changed it to use `os.Create`, which is probably easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

[`image.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) is an interface, and [`*image.Paletted`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Paletted) implements the interface, so for example if you want to save every frame of a GIF into a PNG file, you can just encode every image:

```
for i, frame := range img.Image {
    frameFile, err := os.OpenFile(fmt.Sprintf("%d.png", i+1), os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = png.Encode(frameFile, frame)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Not using defer here because we're in a loop, not a function.
    frameFile.Close()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Go and still unfamiliar with the way it represent an interface implementation.

Comment: @mrd0ll4r's answer is correct. This indeed results in wrong frames.